# PHP SNMP Real Walk returns bad characters

Tags: php, encoding, snmp

I read via PHP function snmp2_real_walk OID value '.1.3.6.1.2.1.17.4.3.1.1' for get MAC address from Cisco switch device. Problem is, that some results (randomly around the 50 results of the 200) return bad characters (yet I have found a mistake if I read only MAC addresses). Ie.:

**correct output examples:**

- [Dot1dTpFdbAddres] => 30 05 5C 38 A7 8C
- [Dot1dTpFdbAddres] =>  C0 7B BC 0E 56 18

**wrong output examples:**

- [Dot1dTpFdbAddres] =>  ,v�?.b  (HEX DUMP: 0 : 20 2c 76 8a 3f 2e 62 20 [ ,v.?.b ])
- [Dot1dTpFdbAddres] =>  ,A8��7  (HEX DUMP: 0 : 20 2c 41 38 82 d9 37 20 [ ,A8..7 ])
- [Dot1dTpFdbAddres] =>  xE�*\ � (HEX DUMP: 0 : 20 78 45 c4 2a 5c 20 d9 20 [ xE.*\ . ])

If I try read OID '.1.3.6.1.2.1.17.4.3.1.1' from program Getif, I have got correct results.

I can't find solution for this problem - can you please help me?

**The tested solution that fails**

- PHP - Chnaged snmp2_real_walk by snmprealwalk
- Changed encoding of files (UTF8, ANSI)
- SNMP longer timeout and try add PHP sleep() function
- PHP directive: snmp_set_oid_numeric_print(1)
- PHP directive: snmp_set_quick_print(true)
- PHP directive: snmp_set_enum_print(true)
- PHP directive: snmp_set_valueretrieval(SNMP_VALUE_LIBRARY and SNMP_VALUE_PLAIN)

**About server:**

- PHP Version 5.5.3
- Apache/2.4.4 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1e PHP/5.5.3
- LAMP are equivalent to WAMP (error too)

**New important informations:**

```
Device return randomly none-hex value for hex values, ie.:
[iso.3.6.1.2.1.17.4.3.1.1.92.38.10.129.123.27] => Hex-STRING: 5C 26 0A 81 7B 1B 
[iso.3.6.1.2.1.17.4.3.1.1.120.69.196.42.25.241] => Hex-STRING: 78 45 C4 2A 19 F1 
[iso.3.6.1.2.1.17.4.3.1.1.120.69.196.42.27.169] => Hex-STRING: 78 45 C4 2A 1B A9 
[iso.3.6.1.2.1.17.4.3.1.1.120.69.196.42.34.45] => STRING: "xE�*\"-"
[iso.3.6.1.2.1.17.4.3.1.1.120.172.192.142.199.214] => STRING: "x�����"
[iso.3.6.1.2.1.17.4.3.1.1.124.30.179.254.9.201] => Hex-STRING: 7C 1E B3 FE 09 C9
```

Mibs are imported correctly to Apache server, devices look fine.

**Is there a way in PHP how to write for snmp2_real_walk() all returned values as Hex-STRING?**

*Similar problems (without results):

- http://forums.cacti.net/viewtopic.php?f=15&t=50806
- http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.network.net-snmp.user/31569
- http://forums.cacti.net/viewtopic.php?f=21&t=46068*

Thanks and best regards,
 Petr

Answer (score 0):

Use the following config:

```
snmp_set_valueretrieval(SNMP_VALUE_LIBRARY);
snmp_set_quick_print(1); 
snmp_set_enum_print(0);
```

Comment: Hello, unfortunately your code consistently output is not working. I tried again different values - without success. Example of output with your code: `[iso.3.6.1.2.1.3.1.1.2.15.1.10.136.4.31] => "00 E0 D8 12 2F 30 "
[iso.3.6.1.2.1.3.1.1.2.15.1.10.136.4.33] => "x��ɱ"
[iso.3.6.1.2.1.3.1.1.2.15.1.10.136.4.34] => "00 25 B3 F8 A3 43 "
[iso.3.6.1.2.1.3.1.1.2.15.1.10.136.4.64] => "؝g�u�"
[iso.3.6.1.2.1.3.1.1.2.15.1.10.136.4.66] => "00 24 81 A0 10 14 "`